# Прозрачная обводка (border)

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет. Верстаю сайт. Создаю веб-дизайн для сайта и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что необходимо сделать прозрачную обводку border div блока. Такой вариант нужен, так как фон динамичный и обводка блоков должна подходить под фон.

Первое, что пришло в голову, это сделать новый блок под основным блоком, ему задать background-image картинку png формата с прозрачностью 50%. нижний блок сделать шире и выше на 2 пх. После с помощью `margin-top: -1px; margin-left: -1px;` сместить нижний блок.

Вариант работающий. Но при помощи resize браузера происходят баги - смещение нижнего блога в произвольную сторону. Так же, мне кажется, этот метод довольно не удобный.

Как можно реализовать прозрачную обводку. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Должно работать:

```
.roundedBox 
{
   background: white;
   border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    -moz-background-clip: border;     
    -webkit-background-clip: border;  
    background-clip: border-box;

    -moz-background-clip: padding;     
    -webkit-background-clip: padding; 
    background-clip: padding-box;

    -moz-background-clip: content;     
    -webkit-background-clip: content;  
    background-clip: content-box;      
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, конечно. Но сделал альтернативный и РАБОТАЮЩИЙ вариант:
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);

Answer (score 1):

```
border-color:transparent;
```

Comment: Необходима полупрозрачность

Answer (score -1):

```
.dropdown-table {border: 1px solid #ccc transparent;}
```

Comment: А вы можете ответить более развёрнуто?